# How do I remove the first or last n characters from a value in q/ kdbstudio?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I've looked into [the underscore for drop/cut](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#_-drop), but this only seems to remove the first or last n entries, not characters. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Connor Gervin had almost what I wanted, but if you want to cast back to a string, you can use `` `$(-3)_'string sym from tab ``

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you're using drop cut on.
Can you provide an example of your values?

Below shows how cut can be used on a sting and then a list of strings.
It uses each right to drop a value from each item.
http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-right

```
q)1_"12456789"
"2456789"
q)
q)1_("12456789";"12456789")
"12456789"
q)
q)1_/:("12456789";"12456789")
"2456789"
"2456789"
```

Comment: Thanks emc211! I'm not sure how to replicate data for kdb, but I've got a table and each entry in one of my columns looks like this: "NVC CN". So I want to remove the rightmost three characters from each entry in my table